# Why is **kwargs outdated?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyword-argument

When I run this code:

```
from pingouin import mediation_analysis, read_dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep = "\t")
print(df)
```

I keep getting this message:

```
OutdatedPackageWarning: The package outdated is out of date. Your version is 0.2.0, the latest is 0.2.1.
Set the environment variable OUTDATED_IGNORE=1 to disable these warnings.
  **kwargs
```

Is there a way of updating **kwargs? And why would **kwargs be outdated in the first place?

Comment: As the error message says, your *local* installation of the package ``outdated`` is outdated. The ``**kwargs`` is just an internal call to the package that triggered the warning – it's *where* they are used, not what they are, that is the problem..

Answer (score 2):

You just didn't read carefully enough. `**kwargs` is not out of date. One of your packages is outdated, and separately from that, your program printed `**kwargs`. Update your `outdated` package.

Comment: How would I find that package? And I thought I had updated everything with conda update --all...

Comment: @thatoneperson “_The package outdated is out of date_”. The package is called “outdated”.

Comment: oh okay thanks! sorry I'm still relatively new to this.